# Selecting by month in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I want to select rows according to the month of a `date` or `timestamp` column like this:

```
SELECT id, name, birthday 
FROM employee.person 
WHERE Month(birthday) > 10;
```

But I only get error messages in PostgreSQL.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use `EXTRACT` function, like this:

```
SELECT id, name, birthday FROM employee.person 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM birthday) > 10;
```

Your problem comes from the fact that there is no such thing as `Month` function in PostgreSQL. Check online documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) to see what you can get instead. `Extract` should be enough.

Comment: I got HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: The downside of this method it cannot utilise an index on the birthday column.

Comment: this hint really worked for me, just being careful that month = '08', is not an integer, therefore must be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can also extract the month name using the following function.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE(REPORT_DATE), 'Month') FROM TABLE_NAME
```