# how do i select the dates with a specific month?

Tags: sql

How do I select the date with a specific month?
For example I have in my table:

```
1-mar-2015
16-mar-2013
12-feb-2016
14-apr-2014
```

And I want to get only the dates from march.
The result should be:

```
1-mar-2015
16-mar-2013
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: For **SQL Server** : [Getting only Month and Year from SQL DATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date)

Comment: For **Oracle** : [get month name from date in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497456/get-month-name-from-date-in-oracle)

Comment: For **Mysql** : [How do I extract Month and Year in a MySQL date and compare them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830987/how-do-i-extract-month-and-year-in-a-mysql-date-and-compare-them)

Comment: For **Postgres** : [Selecting by month in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863156/selecting-by-month-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 2):

Databases have ways of extracting date parts.  The ANSI standard method is:

```
where extract(month from date) = 3
```

Other databases support functions such as `month()` or `to_char()` to achieve the same purpose.